# How to turn off cors in Angular?

Tags: angular, cors

When using `fetch` you can set `mode: 'no-cors'` to avoid cors, is it possible with Angular's `Http`? The server I'm poking doesn't provide cors header, but I don't really need it as it gives the proper response right away, but because of cors issues my browser fires an exception and I cant execute code it `subscribe()` part.

UPD:
Seems like it requires some `JSONP` trickery, but I've no idea how it works. Tried to replace `Http` with `Jsonp`, now I get `JSONP injected script did not invoke callback.` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, figured that out. The server was just throwing `JSON`s back at me with no cors headers, that case is `JSONP`, had to replace `Http` with `Jsonp` and add a `callback=JSONP_CALLBACK` thing to request parameters. Also, request needed a header `accept: application/json`. After all those manipulations everything started working fine.